# How to save html tags with text to database? django & react

Tags: django, django-models

I am using CKEditor to enter text and saving into database. When I retrieve it description, it also shows the html p tags which i dont want. How can I save it into database such that the p tags don't show but tags like  are still applied. Essentially I want to save it as html itself and not text. Is there a way I can do that? Currently I am using TextField to store the description.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `HTMLField` [Django-doc] for this:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    description = models.HTMLField()
```

This will store the HTML in the database, and render it as HTML when you retrieve the object.

Normally, an `HTMLField` will sanitize the HTML to prevent XSS attacks, but you can disable this in case you want to allow arbitrary HTML:

```
description = models.HTMLField(sanitize=False)
```

Note that an `HTMLField` is a `TextField` under the hood; it just uses a special form widget (`AdminHTMLWidget [GitHub]`) and serialization in the ORM layer.

Comment: Where did you find models.HTMLField? I can find any referenses in Django docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the save method of model .
for example whenever the object gets created or update . you just Replace the

Tag Using regex and and can also extra tags with regex .

Example:

```
def save(instance):

    instance.html = instance.html.replace("<p>","<div>").replace("</p>","</div>")
```

You can also use regex instead of replace function .

- You can also save this output of replace or regex into another field and show that chaned html content on the website

Comment: This removes the tags? But I want to keep that tags for when I show it on website. And there might be other tags like <strong> or <i> not just <p> and <div>

Comment: @sash I will suggest you create a custom template tag . 
and do the same thing of replace or regex in it .
suppose your html is
 html= "<div><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p></div>"
if you replace it will replace the Occurence of give string
html.replace("<p>","<div>")
output is "<div><div>1</p><div>1</p><div>1</p></div>"
when you do it for 
html.replace("<p>","<div>").replace("</p>","</div>")

output is "<div><div>1</div>><div>1</div>><div>1</div>></div>"

when you will create the template tag at that time you create a list of tags  that you want to replace and then do the for loop to

Comment: you could use the custom template by docs
here is the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/